# How do you communicate with users who send to your inbox on this site

Tags: support

I got an email from somone who edited my post for readability, which I don't mind, but can someone please tell me how I can email people who send me messages on here  - There seems to be no way to send private messages or emails to users, and I don't want to get into trouble because I cant send a message or communicate in email or privately.

How is this done?

Answer (score 8):

There is no user-to-user private communication mechanism on the site. If you're trying to leave feedback on an edit to a particular post, you can comment on that post and begin with `@name_of_the_person_who_edited`. In your case, you would comment on your question with `@Jakuje Your message here`, and Jakuje would see a notification in their inbox (the tray icon next to the StackExchange logo at the top of the screen). But that comment is posted publicly on the question, and you can only alert certain people that way (the complete list is [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/43020/145982)).

---

Based on some of your [question revisions](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/355141/revisions), you seem confused about how edit diffs work. The revisions page just shows each revision in order. Red crossed-out sections were removed in that revision, and green sections were added, but that's just to help understand what each revision did -- the actual post doesn't look anything like that. It's probably clearer if you use the "side-by-side" view above each diff -- if you ignore the green coloring, the view on the right is what the post looked like after that revision. Edits certainly aren't intended to answer the question, they're a totally separate function.